# How to send a message to a remote syslog by using syslog.h

Tags: c++, linux, syslog

The following code send a message to the file /var/log/syslog.
I have a remote server which is listening in port 514(rsyslog).
Is there any way to change this code so it will send a message to the remote server?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  openlog ("Engine", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
  syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"***Example***");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge using openlog and syslog as you describe will log to the server configured in syslog.conf, thus you cannot specify a server the way you want. You could set up remote server in syslog.conf and that should work.

If you do not wish to do that, you either need to use a library that supports syslog as a sink, or you need to implement your own - which is not very hard.

Comment: There are several, but most include alot more than just the syslog part, poco project is one, you can write your own quite fast by using boost library and boost::asio::ip::udp::socket, others that are more logging libraries are log4cpp, pantheios and i also think google-glog supports syslog.